# exited with code=0 in 0.074 seconds - Output window has no output in Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

A simple print("Hello") will not produce any output so I'm not sure what to do. I've tried pressing ctrl+ F5 but haven't found any effective solutions beyond this. i'm using the VS Code IDE under "Code", please help.

```
exited with code=0 in 0.074 seconds
```

Image of my output terminal:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you've saved your file ? Look in terminal not in output.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the 'Code Runner' extension caused it. You can try to disable it to use 'Python' extension instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have been getting it is because you have code runner extension running on it. Due to which, you are getting code exited 0 error while running the python program.

**Go to the Extensions -> search for (code-runner) -> Disable options (Click)**

Then open the vscode and reopen it.
You may then try to run the python program to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

go to settings and type this --> @ext:formulahendry.code-runner / then you should see something like Code-runner: Show Execution Message
Whether to show extra execution message like [Running] ... and [Done] ...
if there is a mark next to the option remove it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXV5V.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your two extensions could be running together like code runner and the official Microsoft python extensions.

What worked for me personally was to disable the code runner extension, it will say reload required do that and then your vs code will run on the official python extension which means it will work now on the initial stages.

Answer (score 0):

You can always open up the integrated terminal (keycode varies, but the default is ctrl+shift+` ) then run

```
python <file.py>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the third terminal tab and run

```sh
python <filename>
```

The output should be visible in that space.

The output window only shows the status messages and code=0 means it ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution**:

**1.** I had to make sure I was working under the **virtual environment variable** `(venv)` (I wasn't)

**2.** I had to **save** the file I was trying to run **before** running it `Ctrl+S`.

**My problem**:

I was running two terminals opened. In the first one I had an active server, and in the second on I was running the actual file. I was able to make it work:

**Running sever (terminal 1: Python)**
[image]

**Working file (Code)**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

yes Today i faced the same problem
instead of correct output getting code=0 and running
The solution is in the coderunner

1. In addition to  uncheck this Execution Message Whether to show extra execution message like [Running] ... and [Done] ..

you can also check  this run in integrated terminal