# How can i fix Terminal doesn't show any output?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, function, terminal, console.log

only information i got is this:

**[Running] node "/Users/...etc**

**[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.071 seconds**

I pressed the run-button, but the terminal **does not** displays any of the code below.

Files: index.html, script.css, script.js ;

I am working with Visual Studio.

```
let mood = 'sleepy';

console.log("Eigene .changeMood Methode bauen")

const changeMood = (stimmung) => {
   let variable = stimmung
   return variable;
}

changeMood(Happy);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: looks like it's caused by `Code Runner` extension. disabling that extension should fix the problem. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461708/exited-with-code-0-in-0-074-seconds-output-window-has-no-output-in-visual-stud

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Extensions -> search for (code-runner) -> Disable options (Click)

reference: [exited with code=0 in 0.074 seconds - Output window has no output in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461708/exited-with-code-0-in-0-074-seconds-output-window-has-no-output-in-visual-stud)