# python terminal not outputting text

Tags: python-3.x

I know it's probably a duplicate but I didn't manage to find it. but anyways, every time I try to run my code in vscode, it exits normally with code=0, but it doesn't display anything at all on output. how can I fix this?

this is the simple code that I'm trying to run

```
from datetime import datetime

odds = [ 1, 3 , 5 , 7, , 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, ]

rightThisMinute = datetime.today().minute

if rightThisMinute in odds:
   print("this minute seems a little odd!")
else:
    print("not an odd minute.")`
```

[and this is the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7TDn.png)

Comment: you need to look for output in the terminal tab, not the output tab

Answer (score 0):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461708/exited-with-code-0-in-0-074-seconds-output-window-has-no-output-in-visual-stud#:~:text=The%20reason%20you%20have%20been,while%20running%20the%20python%20program.&text=Then%20open%20the%20vscode%20and,to%20get%20the%20desired%20results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461708/exited-with-code-0-in-0-074-seconds-output-window-has-no-output-in-visual-stud#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20you%20have%20been,while%20running%20the%20python%20program.&text=Then%20open%20the%20vscode%20and,to%20get%20the%20desired%20results).

This question might be helpful. As the answers already point out, you might have multiple extensions running on VSCode.

Also try simply printing Hello World to check if it works.

Comment: omg it was actually that! thank you so much!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with your list. It should look like this:

```
odds = [ 1, 3 , 5 , 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35 ]
```

With the list above the code works fine for me. But please read about the modulo function. You really don't need a list of odd numbers.

```
if rightThisMinute % 2 == 0:
   print("Even number")
else:
   print("not an even number")
```